# Google Analytics документация

Tags: google-analytics, поиск-документации

Собственно вопрос Reporting API версии 4. Где можно найти подробную документацию по этой версии API. описание классов и методов и как они работают. Я понимаю что можно открыть код и там сидеть изучать. Но все-таки документацию читать приятнее.
Спасибо за адекватные ответы за ранее.

Answer (score 0):

Всем доброго времени суток. Значить нашел я ресурс где располагаются разные api в том числе и по google api, правда ресур на английском языке но думаю с переводчиком от гугл хрома сейчас не проблема. вот собсна ссылка [КЛАЦ](https://api.kdyby.org/class-Google_Client.html)